# Reset Gnome GLib Schemes

Tags: gnome

I accidently deleted

```
/usr/share/gnome-shell
```

From my PC (Gnome 3.8), so I copied it form my other PC (that has 3.9.1).
Now when I start gnome-shell in the terminal, it says there is no key 'toggle-overview' in

```
org.gnome.shell.keybindings
```

How can I restore those GLib Schemas?

Answer (score 1):

I added this to

```
/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/org.gnome.shell.gschema.xml
```

in the section `keybindings`

```
<key type="as" name="toggle-overview">
  <default>["&lt;Super&gt;o"]</default>
  <summary></summary>
  <description></description>
</key>
```

and then run

```
sudo glib-compile-schemas .
```

in that directory

(I should stop posting questions before trying hard enough, note to self)